# Difference between CUDA level and compute level?

Tags: cuda

What is the difference these two definitions?
If no, does it mean, I will be never able to run code with sm > 21 on the gpu with compute level 2.1?

Comment: I have never heard of either term. Compute capability is the only term I have ever seen referred to in CUDA documentation. What is it you are trying to ask here?

Comment: I told about this: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads
It shows "CUDA 5.5", but the latest sm-level, as I know, is 3.5

Comment: CUDA 5.5 is a completely different concept.  CUDA 5.5 is a software version release.  It's not related to compute capability, or virtual architectures.   CUDA 5.5 represents the compilers and other tools that can be used to build any CUDA code.  CUDA 5.5 compilers can target any compute capability from cc 1.0 to cc 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct.   For a *compute capability* 2.1 device, the maximum code specification (*virtual architecture*/target architecture) you can give it is `-arch=sm_21`    Code compiled for `-arch=sm_30` for example, would not run correctly on a cc 2.1 device

For more information, you can take a look at the `nvcc` [manual section](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#virtual-architectures) which covers virtual architectures, as well as the [manual section](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-steering-gpu-code-generation) which covers the compile switches specifying virtual architecture and compile targets (code architecture).